# Node.js Discord.js UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'calculatedPosition' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am using discord.js, I was making a ban command and I got this error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'calculatedPosition' of undefined`

My code is:

```js
let banUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first())
let bannerHighRole = message.member.highestRole.calculatedPosition;
let getBannedHighRole = banUser.highestRole.calculatedPosition;
if (bannerHighRole < getBannedHighRole) return message.reply("You cannot ban users that have higher roles than you!")
if (bannerHighRole = getBannedHighRole) return message.reply("You cannot ban users that have same highest role!")
```

How can I fix this error?
I'm running the bot on Discord.js v12

Comment: Can you post the full code for context? what version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: v12. Full code of ban is: https://hastebin.com/ekovemidek.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be v11 code or before, check docs to update your other code, but regardless:

They have changed a lot of the camelCase functions like `fetchMessages` into things like `messages.fetch`, might be useful to know.

```js
// you can use message.mentions.members instead of converting a user
let banUser = message.mentions.members.first();
let bannerHighRole = message.member.roles.highest.position;
let getBannedHighRole = banUser.roles.highest.position;
if (bannerHighRole < getBannedHighRole) return message.reply("You cannot ban users that have higher roles than you!");
//you had x = y, which is an assignment
if (bannerHighRole === getBannedHighRole) return message.reply("You cannot ban users that have same highest role!");
```

Also saw the full code and you should prob check if the user has mod/admin before you calculate all of these.